# Why does computing the `round` function fail in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I run the following SQL:

```sql
select round(3.14, 2147483648);
```

It returned:

```
502 Bad Gateway, details:
```

Why this happened?

Comment: 2147483648 is 1 *over* the max value of a signed 32bit integer. Do the missing 'details' say something about "Arithmetic overflow"?